# May MPI_SEND use my input data array as Buffer?

Tags: mpi

As we know, there is a thing called an MPI send buffer used during a send action.
And for following code:

```
MPI_Isend(data, ..., req);
...
MPI_Wait(req, &status)
```

Is it safe to use `data` between `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Wait` ?

That means, will `MPI_Isend` use `data` as the internal send buffer?

And more, if I don't use `data` anymore, could I indicate MPI to use `data` as the send buffer rather than waste time to copy `data`?

BTW, I've heard of `MPI_Bsend`, but I don't think it could save memory and time in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPI provides two kinds of operations: **blocking** and **non-blocking**. The difference between the two is when it is safe to reuse the data buffer passed to the MPI function.

When a **blocking** call like `MPI_Send` returns, the buffer is no longer needed by the MPI library and can be safely reused. On the other hand, **non-blocking** calls only initiate the corresponding operation and let it continue asynchronously. Only after a successful call to a routine like `MPI_Wait` or after a positive test result from `MPI_Test` one can safely reuse the buffer.

As for how the library utilises the user buffer, that is very implementation-specific. Shorter messages are usually copied to internal (for the MPI library) buffers for performance reasons. Longer messages are usually directly read from the user buffer and sent to the network, therefore the buffer will be in use by MPI until the whole message has been sent.

Comment: Thank your response, I'm very relieved and glad to see the library is smart enough.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely not save to use `data` between `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Wait`.
Between `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Wait` you actually don't know when `data` can be reused. Only after `MPI_Wait` you can be sure that `data` is sent and you can reuse it.
If you don't use `data` anymore you should call `MPI_Wait` at the end of your program.

Comment: If you postpone calling `MPI_Wait` until the very end of the program, the send operation might not get actually progressed until the very end of the program too.